# Dynamic grid-ish Flow-Layout using LayoutGroupControl and GroupControl

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am about to write a main menu for a Windows Forms application.

Rather than trying to explain my goal with a wall of text i made a quick(ugly) paint sketch: 
[image]

As you can see here i want the Group Controls to automatically scale with their content(similar to the wrap_content attribute in android) and fit underneath each other if possible.

If anyone knows how to achieve this or even has a sample where he already did achieve it, that would help me massively!

thanks, Felix.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking, but I guess you are looking for a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel) control. You can set its `FlowDirection` to `TopDown`.

Comment: yes you are right, I made a custom method to size my group controls correctly(wrap_content-ish) and then used a FlowLayoutPanel to make them behave like in the above picture, thank you for the answer